# Диаграмма классов Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите как в Eclipse ADT можно автоматически построить диаграмму взаимодействия классов? Если можно - с пошаговой инструкцией. 
Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

ObjectAID UML Explorer - он строит взаимодействия между классами.